# angular 4, how to pass on provider instance

Tags: angular

I have a Mqtt-Service, where i get some live data from (geometry and temperature). 
**Mqtt-Service:**

```
        import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
        import {Paho} from '../../../../Own_paho_sript/geomqttws31';
        import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';


        @Injectable()
        export class MqttdataproviderService {

          history = [
            {
              topic: '',
              timestamp: '',
              data: '',
              geometry: ''
            }
          ];

         mqttform = {

          addmqttadress: '',
          addmqttport: '',
          addmqttspatialfilter: '',
          addmqtttemporalfilter: '',
          addmqtttopicfilter: '',
          addmqttspatialrelation: '',
          addmqttusername: '',
          addmqttpassword: '',
          } ;

          private datamqtt = new Subject<any>();
          msg$ = this.datamqtt.asObservable();
          public msg = [];

         public constructor(private getformvaules: FormToClientService) {

         this.getformvaules.componentMethodCalled$.subscribe(
         () => {
         this.mqttform = this.getformvaules.addmqtt;
         this.methodToGetMyGeoData();
         });

         //to get live data and push the data in the history.
         this.methodToGetMyGeoData();
         }

          methodToGetMyGeoData() {
           // Methodes to subscrib and, connect to the paho 
            client

          this.client.onMessageArrived = (message: Paho.MQTT.Message) => {
              this.onMessage(message);
              this.history.push({
                'topic': message.destinationName,
                'timestamp': message.timestamp,
                'payloadstring': message.payloadString,
                'geometry': message.geometry
              });

          public onMessage(msg$: string) {
            this.geomsg.push(geomsg$);
            this.datageomqtt.next();

          }
          }
```

**FormToClientService:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class FormToClientService {


  addmqtt = {

              addmqttadress: '',
              addmqttport: '',
              addmqttspatialfilter: '',
              addmqtttemporalfilter: '',
              addmqtttopicfilter: '',
              addmqttspatialrelation: '',
              addmqttusername: '',
              addmqttpassword: '',
              } ;
  };


  //Observable string sources
  private componentMethodCallSource = new Subject<any>();

  // Observable string streams
  componentMethodCalled$ = this.componentMethodCallSource.asObservable();

  // Service message commands
  callComponentMethod() {
    this.componentMethodCallSource.next();
  }

  setMqtt (adress: string, port: any, spatial: string, temporal: any, topic: string, username: string, relation: string) {
    this.addmqtt.addmqttadress = adress;
    this.addmqtt.addmqttport = port;
    this.addmqtt.addmqttspatialfilter = spatial;
    this.addmqtt.addmqtttemporalfilter = temporal;
    this.addmqtt.addmqttspatialrelation = relation;
    this.addmqtt.addmqtttopicfilter = topic;
    this.addmqtt.addmqttusername = username;
    console.log('set');
  }
```

I subscribed to the history array  via Observables in 4 different components. 
1. In a map, 2. in a datatable, 3. in a gauge, 4. in a linechart.
They are all quite the same:

```
import {MqttdataproviderService} from '../../protocols/mqtt/mqttdataprovider.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-datatable',
  templateUrl: './datatable.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datatable.component.css'],
})
export class DatatableComponent  {
  rows = [];
  columns = [
    { prop: 'topic' },
    { name: 'payloadstring' },
    { name: 'geometry' },
    { name: 'timestamp' }
  ];
  constructor(private mqttprovider: MqttdataproviderService) {
      this.mqttprovider.msg$.subscribe(() => {
      this.rows = this.mqttprovider.history;
      this.rows = [...this.rows];
    });
}
```

I declared the MqttdataproviderService in my app.module globally as a singleton and everyrhing works fine!


But now i want to create several instances or dynamical instances of the MqttdataproviderService. I have several topics i want to subscribe to and **show the geometry data from the different topics at the same time in the map-component** or in the datable.
For every component (map, datatable, linechart, ...) exists an own window.
 
How could i pass the instance of every created MqttdataproviderService?

Comment: I edited my question, i just didnt wanted to overload the question with unnecessary code.

Answer (score 0):

Angular providers have single instances in injectors they were defined.  Considering that singleton is unwanted here, it shouldn't be class provider (default type) that is instantiated on injection.

If `MqttdataproviderService` class has no injectable dependencies, it doesn't necessarily have to be a provider. It can be defined as value provider, primarily for testability and extensibility reasons:

```
{ provide: MqttdataproviderService, useValue: MqttdataproviderService }
```

If it has dependencies, they should be provided manually on instantiation:

```
mqttprovider: MqttdataproviderService;

constructor(
  @Inject(MqttdataproviderService) private _MqttdataproviderService: typeof MqttdataproviderService,
  formToClientService: FormToClientService
) {
  this.mqttprovider = new this._MqttdataproviderService(formToClientService);
}
```

If it is known that `MqttdataproviderService` class has injectable dependencies, factory provider can be used instead:

```
export function mqttdataproviderServiceFactory (formToClientService: FormToClientService) 
  return () => return new MqttdataproviderService(formToClientService);
}

...
{
  provide: mqttdataproviderServiceFactory,
  useFactory: mqttdataproviderServiceFactory,
  deps: [FormToClientService]
 }
...
```

Then factory function that is used to instantiate `MqttdataproviderService` can be injected:

```
mqttprovider: MqttdataproviderService;

constructor(@Inject(mqttdataproviderServiceFactory) public mqttdataproviderServiceFactory: () => MqttdataproviderService) {
  this.mqttprovider = mqttdataproviderServiceFactory();
}
```

In both cases `FormToClientService` will be a singleton. If this is undesirable, it should be handled in same way as `MqttdataproviderService`.

Comment: this.mqttprovider = new this.MqttdataproviderService(); is not working...

Comment: It [certainly should](http://plnkr.co/edit/IZI7XXxNObXw494Iph0M?p=preview) if you did as suggested above.

Comment: Right! you have to define  MqttdataproviderService @NgModul, but i cant use anymore "this.mqttprovider.msg$" for example...

Comment: You [certainly can](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZHot0Blu2jWN5fOW07j1?p=preview).

Comment: ERROR: 'MqttdataproviderService' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.
ERROR: Property 'mqttprovider' does not exist on type 'DatatableComponent'.

Comment: These are type errors that don't affect runtime. You can resolve them by adding mqttprovider type and renaming MqttdataproviderService property to something else. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-weva4h?file=app/app.module.ts

Comment: Thanks for your help!! Do you know what this means:   this.geomqttprovider = new this._MqttdataproviderService(); ---> ERROR:     Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.

Comment: The code you've posted has no constructor params, `public constructor() {...}`. And the code you're running likely has them and expects that you will specify an argument.

Comment: I dont get it...how could i do this?

Comment: Please, post real code for MqttdataproviderService  that has constructor arguments. The code in the question shouldn't differ from real one that creates the problem, see  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . If you believe it's not the case, please, provide a way to replicate the error, Stackblitz or something.

Comment: You are right! I edited my post und posted the full code. The FormToCLientService just add the formvalues to the MqttService and starts the MqttService at the moment, he get the data from the form to subscribe to the client