# DI abstract class instance, angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I have several components that should all get three services at the same time with the same instance injected. Then i want to "generate" a new instance of my class to inject the services another time and on and on... 
My first thought was that it would be best to create an abstract class and inject all the services there. Any of my components would then extend the abstract class but this approach does not work.

**The abstract class:**

```
import { Component, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import {GeomqttdataproviderService} from '../protocols/geomqtt/geomqttdataprovider.service';
import {MqttdataproviderService} from '../protocols/mqtt/mqttdataprovider.service';
import {CoapdataproviderService} from '../protocols/coap/coapdataprovider.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-abstract',
  templateUrl: './abstract.component.html',
  providers: [
    MqttdataproviderService, GeomqttdataproviderService, CoapdataproviderService 
  ],
  styleUrls: ['./abstract.component.css']
})
export class AbstractComponent  {


  protected GeomqttdataproviderService: GeomqttdataproviderService;
  protected MqttdataproviderService: MqttdataproviderService;
  protected CoapdataproviderService: CoapdataproviderService;

  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    this.GeomqttdataproviderService = injector.get(GeomqttdataproviderService);
    this.MqttdataproviderService = injector.get(MqttdataproviderService);
    this.CoapdataproviderService = injector.get(CoapdataproviderService);
  }


}
```

One of the **consuming components**:

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Injector } from '@angular/core';
    import {AbstractComponent} from '../../abstract/abstract.component';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-gauge',
      templateUrl: './gauge.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./gauge.component.css'],
      providers: [
        AbstractComponent
      ],
    })
    export class GaugeComponent extends AbstractComponent  {

      temp = [];

      data = [
        {
          name: '',
          value: ''
        }
      ];
    constructor(injector: Injector) {

        super(injector);


        this.CoapdataproviderService.msg$.subscribe(() => {
          this.temp = [{name: this.CoapdataproviderService.coapform.addcoaptopicfilter, value: this.CoapdataproviderService.msg}]; 
          this.temp = this.data;
          this.data = [{name: this.CoapdataproviderService.coapform.addcoaptopicfilter, value: this.CoapdataproviderService.msg.slice(-1)[0]  }];
        });

        this.GeomqttdataproviderService.geomsg$.subscribe(() => {
          this.temp = [{name: this.GeomqttdataproviderService.geomqttform.addgeomqtttopicfilter, value: this.GeomqttdataproviderService.geomsg}];  // nur das letzte wird angezeigt
          this.temp = this.data;
          this.data = [{name: this.GeomqttdataproviderService.geomqttform.addgeomqtttopicfilter, value: this.GeomqttdataproviderService.geomsg.slice(-1)[0]  }];

        });

         this.MqttdataproviderService.msg$.subscribe(() => {    
          this.temp = [{name: this.MqttdataproviderService.mqttform.addmqtttopicfilter, value: this.MqttdataproviderService.msg}]; 
          this.temp = this.data;
          this.data = [{name: this.MqttdataproviderService.mqttform.addmqtttopicfilter, value: this.MqttdataproviderService.msg.slice(-1)[0]  }];
        });
    }}
```

iI always get the ERROR that all my Services are missing in the gauge-component. But i dont want to declare them in app.module, because i need a new instance every time i inject the abstract class in all the components.

Answer (score 1):

`providers: [AbstractComponent]` doesn't make sense and won't work as you expect. It will create a new instance of `AbstractComponent` class that can be injected, which is not desirable in any situation.

As of now, [decorator annotations cannot be inherited](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13764). `providers` property should be pasted from `AbstractComponent` to `Component` annotation in all child classes.

For DRYer code the array can be exported and reused in all classes that require these providers:

```
export const DATA_PROVIDERS = [
    MqttdataproviderService, GeomqttdataproviderService, CoapdataproviderService 
];

...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-abstract',
  templateUrl: './abstract.component.html',
  providers: [DATA_PROVIDERS],
  styleUrls: ['./abstract.component.css']
})
...
```

Comment: But, how could i use one instance for all the components? When i am providing DATA_PROVIDERS in my components , only one component is showing my data, but i want that all the the consuming components are showing my data at the same time!

Comment: Then it's the opposite of what you're trying to do for same providers in previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48627829/angular-4-how-to-pass-on-provider-instance/48628702#48628702 . If you don't need multiple provider instances, you don't need to define `providers` in components, it should be defined in a module instead.

Comment: What i want to do is: Take one DataProviderService with own instance and show the data at the same time in three consuming components. Then create another instance from the same DataProviderService and show the data at the three consuming components, but now with the new instance of the newly created DataProviderService.

Comment: It depends on the condition that determines these 3 components. Are they grouped by 3 in DOM? You need a proper injector hierarchy in order to make this possible. You're running into XY problem. In order to solve it, the question should have clear problem statement that explains your situation. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that shows how these services and components are used would be helpful, there's no need to provide full class implementations, they can be several lines long.