# Angular2 - AOT - Define Dynamic Component Provider

Tags: angular

i have some trouble with angular2 component providers. I would like provide some providers defined on component level

```
@Component({
    selector: "component",
    template: 'hello',
    providers: [SomeService]
})
```

this will work, if you direct set the Service to the providers. In my case, which provider to add to the providers list, will provide from different modules.

I create a static class, that all Modules can provide his own component providers for this component, but the AOT Build will return an error during build:

> Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'AppBridge', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol brdigeProvide.

I tried this as example:

```
@Component({
    selector: "component",
    template: 'hello',
    providers: [AppBridge.getProviders('A')]
})
```

AppBridge.getProviders will return an array with provide definition e.g.

```
[{ provide: AbstractMyService, useClass: MyService }, OtherService]
```

is there a way to provide services on component? I need this, because the module that provide this component, should not have any reference to other 'modules' inside the application.

will be happy i you can give my a tip. Maybe this is not possible Oo because angular2/x need everything statically.

i create an example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-provider

after talk with @estus
here some more details. The background of my problem is, that a FESM will load on runtime. This module should provide services for a component that will be called on runtime. This component will create n-times, and the services should also create n-times for each component.

Comment: *is there a way to provide services on component?* - no. Everything should be static, so it's processed at compile time rather than run time. That's the point of AOT.

Comment: yes yes this is my biggest fear, that this not not possible on AOT build 

:/ its very hard to build an real dynamic app with angular. I need to provide services on runtime, depends on which modules are loaded on my application. Those modules will provide some providers for this component.

Comment: You possibly have XY problem that can be addressed more or less conveniently in a different way. Consider re-asking the question with all information that is necessary to understand your case. A http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve will be helpful. Real names instead of unnecessary abstractions like `MyService` will make more sense.

Comment: ok i see, my idea was to define to problematic in general way, because i see that problem not directly an implementation detail, more an angular framework part. I provide a simple application on stackblitz, its that example concrete enough or need more specific details ?

Comment: Angular is opinionated and full of limitations, once you know them well enough, you can use it efficiently. From what I see in the stackblitz, AppBridge provider map doesn't provide any practical benefits here, except it's a neat idea that doesn't play well with the framework and thus isn't really neat after all. Maybe the example was oversimplified, but I see no place for dynamic behaviour here. You could go with constants for provider arrays, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-provider-jerkr9?file=app/hello.component.ts

Comment: you are right. I updated my question and add more details about the main problem.

Comment: I'm still not sure what possible options would be in your case. It's unclear why it's so, *FESM will load on runtime. This module should provide services for a component that will be called on runtime*. This is why I suspected that it's XY problem. The concept of AppBridge global provider map should be disregarded because it didn't take Angular specificity into account, and you need to think out of the box.

Comment: This probably could be solved with routing, there will be multiple injectors in lazy loaded modules. It if the real issue is that just these services don't have to be singletons, they could be changed to factories, see mqttdataproviderServiceFactory here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48627829/angular-4-how-to-pass-on-provider-instance/48628702#48628702

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164830/discussion-between-moohkooh-and-estus).

Comment: Tbh I'm trying to stay away from chats on SO, they don't work well for offline talks.